# moment.js returning incorect seconds for datetime datetime

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, momentjs

I am using **moment.js** library with **Timezone** and **BusinessDays** extensions with vuejs to create a datetime format to save in mysql database, let me show you the code.

```
    import moment from 'moment-timezone'
    import momentBusiness from 'moment-business-days'
    
    momentBusiness.updateLocale('us', {
        workingWeekdays: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    });
    
    var currentdate=momentBusiness().tz('America/Resolute').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
    console.log(currentdate); //returns 2020-07-09 09:07:60
    
    console.log(momentBusiness().tz('America/Resolute').add(4, "hours").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")); //returns 2020-07-09 13:07:61
    console.log(momentBusiness().tz('America/Resolute').businessAdd(5).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")); //returns 2020-07-16 09:07:61
```

The formatting works just fine as you can see from above the seconds crosses 60 mark which result  in exception from Mysql, very wierd issue though, does anyone know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capital `S` is for millisencond, you should use lower `s` and it will be fixed.

Check the `moment` library documentation at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Oh Lol, I totally missed that part i thought S stands for seconds, thankyou so much for  the help, keep up the good work!